# Salesforce filter managed package with regex?

Tags: managed-package, regular-expressions

I utilized the below regex pattern to filter managed package object from all custom object retrieved by Describe method.

```
Pattern regEx = Pattern.compile('^\\w*?__\\B\\w*__');
```

I tried to understand the above patter which i got from internet.

w - means any

* - means one or more

B - means bunch of words

what is (?) means . ?  Looking forward little help here to understand the pattern.

I got the object name filter by the above regex (i.e test_object__c).

Comment: Put that in at regex101.com and it will explain each piece for you

Comment: cool. i ill try that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
^      # matches the beginning of a string  
\\w*?  # matches zero or more word characters [A-Za-z0-9_]  
__     # matches two underscores  
\\B    # matches a non-word boundary  
\\w*   # matches zero or more word characters [A-Za-z0-9_] 
__     # matches two underscores
```

Of note:

- using a lazy match instead of a greedy match here, `\\w*?`, doesn't make a difference since the strings you will be matching against will probably not have more than two sets of `__`, and you aren't using capturing groups anyways.
- the `\\B` term is superfluous. The underscore characters on either side of it are word characters, and adding more word characters between them would not introduce a word boundary.

Here's an example of some strings matched and not matched by this regex:

```
Pattern MyPattern = Pattern.compile('^\\w*?__\\B\\w*__');
list<String> TestStrings = new list<String>{
    'NameSpace__CustomObject__c',                                       // TRUE
    'CustomObject__c',                                                  // FALSE
    'StandardObject',                                                   // FALSE
    'public static void methodName(NameSpace__CustomObject__c co){',    // FALSE
    'NameSpace__1___c',                                                 // TRUE
    'NameSpace__Custom__Object__c',                                     // TRUE
    '__here__'                                                          // TRUE
};

for (String s : TestStrings){
    Matcher MyMatcher = MyPattern.matcher(s);
    system.debug(MyMatcher.find());
}
```